# How to sort the RecyclerView on each new item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView on which i add items from another RecyclerView, each item has a property called "TYPE" and it's value can be "FASE1", "FASE2" and up to "FASE8".

When a new item is added to that list or removed i need to sort it based on the TYPE values.

So all items has to be sorted like ITEM1 FASE1 > ITEM2 FASE2 ....

Till now i was just adding or removing items from the RecyclerView like the following:

Here is the code from RecyclerView Adapter of the RecyclerView which adds items to the other RecyclerView.

```
private void addOrRemove(int position, boolean add) {
        // piattiItems is a reference to ArrayList<ItemPTERM> from the Adapter of the RecyclerView where i have to add the items
        Item prodotto = mFilteredList.get(position); // getting item from current RecyclerView
        ItemPTERM prodottoAggiunto = piattiAdapter.getItemByCode(prodotto.getCodice()); // cheking if there is yet the same item in the RecyclerView where i have to add it
   if (add) {
        piattiItems.add(nuovoProdotto(prodotto)); // adding new item
        piattiAdapter.notifyItemInserted(size);
        recyclerPiatti.scrollToPosition(size);
   }else {
        piattiItems.remove(prodottoAggiunto); // removing item
        piattiAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is:

1. `RecyclerView` should just be responsible for displaying your data, it shouldn't know the order of your `List` data.
2. Your `List` data should be responsible for the order.

---

So, after you add new item to your `RecylerView`, first update/resort your `List`, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` object. Or just call `sumitList()` if you're using `ListAdapter` with `DiffUtil`, which will just update the changed items rather than updating the whole `List` like `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by defining an order relation among the `ItemPTERM`s by implementing the `Comparable<ItemPTERM>` interface with `ItemPTERM` or by creating a `Comparator` that implements `Comparator<ItemPTERM>`.

In the latter, you should implement the [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method. I'm supposing that "TYPE" is an `Enum` to make things simpler; by the way if it's a `String` you should implement a specific algorithm for your goal.

When `comparator` is ready, you can add elements to `piattiItems` as always and call `Collections.sort(piattiItems, comparator)` to sort the `ArrayList`. Now you can get the index of the newly added item and use it to tell your `RecyclerView` the position of this item. `RecyclerView` will do the rest by showing the item at the correct position!

```
private Comparator<ItemPTERM> mComparator = new Comparator<>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(ItemPTERM o1, ItemPTERM o2) {
        return o1.type.compareTo(o2.type); // supposing that type is enum
    }
}

private void addOrRemove(int position, boolean add) {
        Item prodotto = mFilteredList.get(position);
        ItemPTERM prodottoAggiunto = piattiAdapter.getItemByCode(prodotto.getCodice());
   if (add) {
        ItemPTERM newItem = nuovoProdotto(prodotto);
        piattiItems.add(newItem);
        Collections.sort(piattiItems, mComparator); // sorts after adding new element
        int index = piattiItems.indexOf(newItem); // gets the index of the newly added item
        piattiAdapter.notifyItemInserted(index); // uses the index to tell the position to the RecyclerView
        recyclerPiatti.scrollToPosition(index);
   }else {
        piattiItems.remove(prodottoAggiunto);
        piattiAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
   }
}
```